# Postgresql - Map array aggregates into a single array in a particular order

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have a PostgreSQL table containing a column of 1 dimensional array data. I wish to perform an aggregate query on this column, obtaining min/max/mean for each element of the array as well as the group count, returning the result as a 1 dimensional array. The array lengths in the table may vary, but I can be certain that in any grouping I perform, all arrays will be of the same length.

In a simple form, say my arrays are of length 2 and have readings for x and y, I want to return the result as 
*{Min(x), Max(x), Mean(x), Min(y), Max(y), Mean(y), Count(*)}

I am able to get a result in the form *{Min(x), Min(y), Max(x), Max(y), Mean(x), Mean(y) Count(*)} but I can't get from there to my desired result.

Here's an example showing where I am so far (this time with arrays of length 3, but without the mean aggregation as there isnt one for arrays built in to pgSql): 
([SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/061426/1/0))

```
CREATE TABLE my_test(some_key numeric, event_data bigint[]);

INSERT INTO my_test(some_key, event_data) VALUES
(1, {11,12,13}),
(1, {5,6,7}),
(1, {-11,-12,-13});

SELECT MIN(event_data) || MAX(event_data) || COUNT(event_data)  FROM my_test GROUP BY some_key;
```

The above gives me

*{11,12,13,-11,-12,-13,3}*

However, I don't know how to transform a result like the above into what I want, which is:

*{11,-11,12,-12,13,-13,3}*

What function should I use to transform the above?

Note that the aggregation functions above don't exactly match with those I am using to get min, max - I'm using the [aggs_for_vecs](https://github.com/pjungwir/aggs_for_vecs) extension to give me min, max and mean.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using array operations and aggregation:

```
select x.some_key,
       array_agg(u.val order by x.n, u.nn)
from (select t.some_key, ed.n, min(val) as minval, max(val) as maxval
      from my_test t cross join lateral
           unnest(t.event_data) with ordinality as ed(val, n)
      group by t.some_key, ed.n
     ) x cross join lateral
     unnest(array[x.minval, x.maxval]) with ordinality u(val, nn)
group by x.some_key;
```

Personally, I would prefer an array with three elements and the min/max as a record:

```
select x.some_key, array_agg((x.minval, x.maxval) order by x.n)
from (select t.some_key, ed.n, min(val) as minval, max(val) as maxval
      from my_test t cross join lateral
           unnest(t.event_data) with ordinality as ed(val, n)
      group by t.some_key, ed.n
     ) x 
group by x.some_key;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=fa12cef5744671da5d29b8cca3ef4124) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks, there were a few new terms for me like the lateral join, so it took me a while to understand how the query works. Nice that they save me from to install a db extension to perform the aggregation on the arrays.

The alternative formatting of the result is a valid suggestion, but the query result must match an agreed format in a rest api.

If I may ask for one more refinement to your example, how should I append the row count once at the end of the result array? (in order to get something like {avg(x), min(x), max(x), avg(y), min(y), max(y), **count(*)**}

Comment: @IanFerguson . . . If this works, you might consider accepting the answer.  As for the row count, I would suggest that you ask a *new* question; this one is complicated enough.

Comment: Including the count in the result array was part of my original question, so it hasn't quite solved the problem for me. I really appreciate your answer though, and I would upvote it, but as a new user SO doesn't allow me to.